# Dump tuple into YAML file in a specific format

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have a specific format that I would like to dump the tuple into YAML file. I have the following code that I have tried running to dump the tuple into YAML file. From the following code below, I tried to add a pair of tuple (x, y) into the list by using append(). After which, I would dump the list back into the YAML file. My question is that, is it possible for me to keep the same specific format of the file when I am dumping back to the YAML file?

```
import ruamel.yaml

def addObstacles():

    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
    with open('input.yaml') as f:
        doc = yaml.load(f)

    x = 5
    y = 6
    doc['map']['obstacles'].append(list((x,y)))

    with open('input.yaml', 'w') as f:
        yaml.dump(doc, f)
```

The output of the following file is as follows:

```
map:
  dimensions: [8, 8]
  obstacles:
  - !!python/tuple [4, 5]
  - !!python/tuple [2, 0]
  - !!python/tuple [1, 1]
  - !!python/tuple [0, 5]
  - !!python/tuple [2, 5]
  - !!python/tuple [4, 4]
  - !!python/tuple [7, 5]
  - !!python/tuple [1, 4]
  - !!python/tuple [6, 7]
  - !!python/tuple [6, 3]
  - !!python/tuple [1, 7]
  - !!python/tuple [3, 6]
  - - 5
    - 6
```

The intended output of the file is as follows:

```
map:
  dimensions: [8, 8]
  obstacles:
  - !!python/tuple [4, 5]
  - !!python/tuple [2, 0]
  - !!python/tuple [1, 1]
  - !!python/tuple [0, 5]
  - !!python/tuple [2, 5]
  - !!python/tuple [4, 4]
  - !!python/tuple [7, 5]
  - !!python/tuple [1, 4]
  - !!python/tuple [6, 7]
  - !!python/tuple [6, 3]
  - !!python/tuple [1, 7]
  - !!python/tuple [3, 6]
  - !!python/tuple [5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you append a list, you'll get a list, but I assume you tried that because a plain tuple would
not work, because you actually unveiled a bug in ruamel.yaml.

This can be easily remedied with two lines of code, and by specifying the `default_flow_style`:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

if ruamel.yaml.version_info < (0, 16, 7):
   ruamel.yaml.representer.RoundTripRepresenter.add_representer(tuple, 
                         ruamel.yaml.representer.Representer.represent_tuple)

def addObstacles():

    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
    yaml.default_flow_style = None   # default is False, which would get you a block sequence
    with open('input.yaml') as f:
        doc = yaml.load(f)
    doc['map']['obstacles'].append((5, 6))

    yaml.dump(doc, sys.stdout)


addObstacles()
```

that way you get what you want:

```
map:
  dimensions: [8, 8]
  obstacles:
  - !!python/tuple [4, 5]
  - !!python/tuple [2, 0]
  - !!python/tuple [1, 1]
  - !!python/tuple [0, 5]
  - !!python/tuple [2, 5]
  - !!python/tuple [4, 4]
  - !!python/tuple [7, 5]
  - !!python/tuple [1, 4]
  - !!python/tuple [6, 7]
  - !!python/tuple [6, 3]
  - !!python/tuple [1, 7]
  - !!python/tuple [3, 6]   # add one after this
  - !!python/tuple [5, 6]
```

(I added the comment in the YAML input file I used).

Comment: I didn't realize that I unveiled a bug, thanks again @Anthon!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you really need `ruamel.yaml` or not. [PyYAML](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) does just what you need out-of-the-box:

```py
import yaml

def addObstacles():
    with open('in.yaml') as f:
        doc = yaml.load(f)

    doc['map']['obstacles'].append((5, 6))

    with open('out.yaml', 'w') as f:
        yaml.dump(doc, f)
```

Comment: Although this might work for the restricted example of the OP, if you recommend downgrading to PyYAML, you should at least list the disadvantages of doing so.